# php using preg_replace to replace this string

Tags: php, replace, preg-replace

I want to replace this string
The first word 1/4W may be different
The character W it may be an upper case or a lower case

```
<?php
$str="1/4W this is string"; // 1/4W can be 1/16W, 1/2W, 1W,2w
$str=preg_replace(("/^\d.W/", "", $str);
var_dump($str);
```

I have tested but I think it is not exact

Answer (score 2):

Use this regex: `^\d+(?:/\d+)?w`

```
$str="1/4W this is string"; // 1/4W can be 1/16W, 1/2W, 1W,2w
$str=preg_replace(("~^\d+(?:/\d+)?w~i", "", $str);
```

**Explanation:**

```
~       : regex delimiter
  ^     : start of string
  \d+   : 1 or more digits
  (?:   : start non capture group
    /   : a slash
    \d+ : 1 or more digits
  )?    : end group, optional
  w     : w
~i      : regex delimiter, case insensitive
```

Comment: in the result i have à space in the begin of string i can use trim to remove this space but can you remove space by regex

Comment: i have add \s to the regex "~^\d+(?:/\d+)?w\s~i" is correct?

Comment: i have other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44883916/php-capture-with-preg-replace-for-moving-this-string-captured

Comment: @user8247367: Yes, just add `\s` at the end.

Comment: @user8247367: see my answer for other question.